# How to create a new Workbench Managed Notebook using REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

How can I create a new Managed Notebook programmatically?
I want to use Notebooks API REST but has not found an example.

Reference [Link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.runtimes/create)

Answer (score 2):

To create a new Managed notebook you can use the following example:

```
BASE_ADDRESS=notebooks.googleapis.com
LOCATION=us-central1
PROJECT_ID=gogasca-sandbox
AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)

RUNTIME_BODY="{
  'access_config': {
        'access_type': 'SINGLE_USER',
        'runtime_owner': 'gogasca@google.com'
        },
  'virtual_machine': {
    'virtual_machine_config': {
      'data_disk': {
         'initialize_params': {
            'disk_size_gb': 200,
            'disk_type': 'PD_SSD',
        }
      },
      'container_images': [{
        'repository': 'gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu', 'tag': 'latest'
        }],
      'metadata': {
        'file_to_load_1':'https://test.google.com/v2/models/versions/trainable_v1.0/zip',
      },
      'machine_type':'n1-standard-4',
      'accelerator_config': {
        'type': 'NVIDIA_TESLA_T4',
        'core_count': '1'
      }
    }
  },
  'software_config':{
    'post_startup_script':'gs://gcp-scripts/step01.sh'
}
}"

RUNTIME_NAME=gogasca-managed-notebook

curl -X POST https://${BASE_ADDRESS}/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$LOCATION/runtimes?runtime_id=$RUNTIME_NAME -d "${RUNTIME_BODY}" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $AUTH_TOKEN" -v
```

Google Cloud SDK is in progress.
Terraform module just got released.