# How to create a new VertexAI Workbench Managed Notebook using gcloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

There is a gcloud command to create a user-managed notebook instance.

```
gcloud notebooks instances create
```

Is is possible to create a managed notebook with gcloud?

It looks to be possible in the [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70223161/how-to-create-a-new-workbench-managed-notebook-using-rest-api). I can't find a gcloud reference.

Comment: We will release the gcloud SDK in the upcoming 2 weeks, right now you can use Terraform, Python Libraries and REST API only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @gogasca, the gcloud SDK for creating managed notebook is currently under work. Meanwhile you can try client libraries and REST API to create the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcloud notebooks runtimes` since version 399, you can get th latest SDK version via `gcloud components update`